# How can I call script inside script to refresh my Partial View in JavaScript with Ajax MVC asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

How can I call script inside another AJAX script to refresh my Partial View or maybe there is another way for refresh my div=itemsTable.

First script in section Scripts is for display my div=itemsTable with data from webservice and database.
Second script is for Buying item from shop when user will click Buy. After user purchase an item, this script should run first script for refresh data.

More information about this in code below.

My View: **List**

```
      <div id="itemsTable">
        Loading data...
    </div>

    @section scripts {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function webServiceScript() {
                if ("webService" in window) {
                  var ws = new webService("ws://some_webService");

                    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                        var receivedmsg = evt.data;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Store/ListPartial',
                            data: receivedmsg,
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: "html",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            error: function (err) {
                                alert('Error: ' + err.statusText);
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                $('#itemsTable').html(result);
                            },

                 [................]

                 };

                 }
            });
    // Script above refreshing data in my partialView (<div id="itemsTable">)



    // When someone will click "Buy" button on my PartialView, it will run the following script.
            function sendRequest(id, price) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    var request =
                    {
                        "Id": id,
                        "Price": price
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Store/Buy', // this method changing quantity of items and return enum (result). That's why i need to refresh my partialView
                        data: JSON.stringify(request),
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert('Error: ' + err.statusText);
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            switch (result) {
                                case "0":
                                    alert("Success!");
                                    $('#itemsTable').loadScript(webServiceScript()); 
// This doesn't work. Somehow i want to refresh my itemsTable
// Also i was trying like this: $('#itemsTable').load('@Url.Action("ListPartial", "Store", null )');
// However method ListPartial in Controller Store expect data from webServiceScript, so unfortunately it's wrong solution
                                    break;
                                case "1":
                                    alert("Fail!");
                                    break;
                               }
                        },
                        async: true,
                        processData: false
                    });
                }
            };
    </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax.BeginForm in the main view:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Buy", "Product", new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
        OnFailure = "onFailure"
    }, new { id = "BuyProductForm" })) -- this id is the id of the form
```

Once you hit "Buy" button, the ajax form will call this OnSuccess to call the below script and from here you can call your first script from which you can update the first div.

```
    function onSuccess(result) {
        if (result) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.